# Model custom validation passing true even though it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very confused about this. My model has the following custom validation:

```
def custom_validation
    errors[:base] << "Please select at least one item" if @transactionparams.blank?
end
```

Basically it's checking to make sure that certain parameters belonging to a different model are not blank.

```
def request_params
    @requestparams = params.require(:request).permit(:detail, :startdate, :enddate) 
    @transactionparams = params["transaction"]
    @transactionparams = @transactionparams.first.reject { |k, v| (v == "0") || (v == "")}
end
```

If it's not blank, then what happens is that the record is saved, and then all kinds of other things happen.

```
def create
    request_params
    @request = @user.requests.create(@requestparams)
    if @request.save
        ...
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

If the record is not saved, the re-rendered `new` view then shows what the errors are that stopped `@request` from being created. The problem is that whether or not `@transactionparams.blank?` is true or false, the record always fails to save, and I checked this specifically with a `puts` in the log.

What's happening? I read through the docs because I thought that maybe custom validators couldn't be used on other variables... but that's not the case...

Thanks!

Comment: How is the model getting `@transactionparams`? In the model, you won't have access to the controller instance variables. How does the model have access to `#params`? `#request_params` must be in the controller. `@transactionparams` in the model must always be nil. There might also be a difference between `params[:transactions]` and `params["transaction"`. Add `Rails.logger.debug variable` throughout to verify each value. `@arrayvariable.first.reject{}` will always fail too, because `#first` selects one value. It is no longer an array and `#reject` will not work. Unless you have nested arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK actually read up on related articles. It's bad practice to ever access a variable from the controller in the model. That's why... If i put the `puts` inspection in the model not controller, `@transactionparams` is always nil.